# Pico TTS stress

Tags: text-to-speech, diacritics, stress

I'm using the SVOX Pico TTS with Italian language. Lot's of words are pronounced with a wrong "stress" - i.e. like the accent mark is placed in the wrong place.

Is there a syntax to force the stress wherever I want? 
Or any ohter hints to correctly format sentences: accent marks, signs, symbols etc...